# How can we create our own React.js components as CDN links?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cdn

I have a Chatbot component in my Next.js app and I want anyone to use to as a chatbot in their website using <script tag. Suppose I put component in my public folder to have public access.

How can I implement this kind of functionality so that anyone can add this link in the script tag of their application and have access to my Chatbot

```
<script type="module" src="https://my-app-url/Chatbot.js" defer></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use an `iframe`.

You can host your Next.js app with a page that only contains the chatbot component and set the background color as transparent.

```
background-color : transparent;
```

Then, anyone with access to your app can use an `iframe` to embed the chatbot in their own website. Adding `allowtransparency="true"` will achieve your desired effect.

```
<iframe src="https://your-nextjs-app/chatbot-page" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

[more info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-transparent-iframe/) on iframe allowtransparency.

---

To create the iframe with javascript:

```
// Create the iframe element
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// Set the iframe attributes
iframe.src = 'https://your-nextjs-app/chatbot-page';
iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
iframe.style.bottom = '0';
iframe.style.right = '0';
iframe.style.width = '400px';
iframe.style.height = '600px';
iframe.style.border = 'none';
iframe.style.opacity = '0.5';
iframe.style.zIndex = '9999';
iframe.allowtransparency = true;
iframe.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

// Append the iframe to the document body
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Cant i use something like cdn or <script>, its a requirement. What is the process to do with cdn or script

Comment: You can use a script served with cdn to create an iframe element and append it to the body. But you would still need to host the app with a transparent chatbot page. I've added the script to create an iframe in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it kinda works, but suppose iframe width and height is 500px, so the its takes the place of 500px in the site its integrated to, and cant do anything in that space.

Comment: The site can set the size of the iframe with css or set ‘display’ to ‘none’ if they don’t need it. They have full control to resize or hide it whenever they want.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot.
One more question plz, There is this site called sitecompanion, they exactly what I am trying to do, they give you script like this to integrate bot with any website.
<script src="https://static.sitecompanion.ai/js/chat.js?bot=abcdef" defer></script>
Checkout this link. Any idea how they do it?

Comment: I've added another answer showing how to build your component into a js file, similar to how sitecompanion did it.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the component, create HTML template and share the CDN Link

Host the HTML file (`ChatbotTemplate.html`) and the built JavaScript file (`Chatbot.build.js`) on a server or CDN accessible to others.

-- HTML Template

```
<div id="chatbot-container"></div>
<script type="module" src="https://my-app-url/Chatbot.build.js" defer></script>
```

Users can then include the following script tag in their HTML file to embed the chatbot:

```
<script type="module" src="https://your-cdn-url/Chatbot.build.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Building a single react component with create-react-app

**Step 1:** initiate a new react project with `create-react-app`

run `npx create-react-app chatbot-component`

**Step 2:** configure the project to build a single component.

Remove everything except `public/index.html` and `src/index.js`

Your folder structure should look like this:

[image: folder structure]

Delete everything in `index.html`, and replace everything in `index.js` with this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <h1>hello world</h1>
  );
};

const div = document.createElement("div");

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(div);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Component />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// append element to body or wherever you want.
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

**Step 3:** run build

run `npm run build` to build the project.

You should see this in you build folder:

[image]

The `main.{hash}.js` is what you want, you can rename it and host it on a cdn. Any HTML page with this script should see `<h1>Hello world</h1>` in their body.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/9t06fh3k/) an example of the build result.